# How to use a database entry as a meta description with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a blog and would like to make the meta description unique to each blog post. I was going to use a database field `:summary` to pull text from to fill the `@page_description = '';` in the controller.

How would I enter this into the `posts_controller` so it would use the `t.string "summary"` that would be with each post?

posts_controller:

```
def show
  @title = 'My Blog';
  @page_description = '';
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comment = current_user.comments.build if logged_in?
end
```

Schema.rb:

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.string "title"
t.text "body"
t.string "summary"
t.string "thumbnail_link"
```

end

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the summary after getting the post

posts_controller:

```
def show
  @title = 'My Blog';
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @page_description = @post.summary;
  @comment = current_user.comments.build if logged_in?
end
```

And add a validation in the model

Post Model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :summary, uniqueness: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want to populate it with the first 160 chars of the body text right? Why don't you just create an instance method for that?

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  def meta_descr
    return body[0..160]
  end
end
```

And use it like this:

```
def show
  @title = 'My Blog';
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @page_description = @post.meta_descr
  @comment = current_user.comments.build if logged_in?
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I accepted the other answer since it was spot on with what I was trying to do. This answer has some good use cases that I might use later for something else!

Comment: Well actually, you shouldn't deal with setting page meta from controller in the first place. So while this does answer your question, I wouldn't consider it a best practice. This kind of bahavior belongs in the view. Read this article: http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-page-titles/

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, it should be very useful. With the answer you provided, do you know how to return the `:description` from a db instead of `body`?

Comment: Would using `@page_description = @post.description[0..300];` in my `def show` work?

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't handle that kind of logic in the controller. This has something to do with the instance of the model, so it should go in the Model.

Comment: just change the `return body[0..160]` into `return description[0..300]`